# Telegram API (TDLib), как получить chat_id для отправки сообщений?

Tags: api, telegram, tdlib

Я только изучаю TDLib (https://core.telegram.org/tdlib/), установил на сервере версию для PHP. Далее, удалось авторизоваться клиентом по вводу кода, получить список чатов (`$client->query(json_encode(['@type'=>'getChats', 'offset_order'=>'9223372036854775807', 'offset_chat_id'=>0, 'limit'=>10]), 10);`), отправить сообщение в известный мне чат (один из списка).

Но как быть с контактами, с которыми у меня ещё не было чатов?

Я нашел, что контакт можно добавить запросом: `$client->query(json_encode(['@type' => 'importContacts', 'contacts' => [['phone_number' => '+ХХХХХХХХХХХХ',],]]), 2);`, а запрос возвращает **user_ids**, но для отправки этого недостаточно, т.к. требуется указывать **chat_id**

Подскажите, как по номеру телефона получить **chat_id**, чтобы инициировать чат с пользователем?

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл! Есть метод createPrivateChat, в него параметром передал user_ids и в ответ получил id чата и прочие параметры! Это и есть решение!

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]